# no matching function call, no known conversion

Tags: c++, arrays, stack

I'm trying to implement a stack using an array. I'm receiving is in main while trying to pass the stack into an argument after the else statement. What am I misunderstanding? Any help would be appreciated!

Error is in main at `stack(input, &stack)`

> No matching function call to ‘calc(std::string&, MyStack*)
>
> No known conversion for argument 2 from ‘Stack*’ to ‘int&’.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is self-explanatory.  There is no overloaded version of `calc()` that matches the parameters you are passing it.  You declared `calc()` as:

```
void calc(const string &input, int &stack)
```

The error message is saying that you are passing in a `MyStack*` pointer where an `int` is expected instead.

```
stack.calc(input, &stack); // <-- stack is a MyStack, so &stack is a MyStack*
```

For that matter, your implementation of `calc()` doesn't even *USE* the `stack` parameter at all!  So just remove it altogether:

```
void calc(const string &input)

...

stack.calc(input);
```

There is no reason for `main()` to pass in its `stack` object as a parameter when `calc()` already has access to the object via its implicit `this` parameter.

Also, the `x` and `y` local variables inside of `calc()` are not being initialized with any values before they are used to calculate the `result`.  You probably meant to *parse`the`input` to extract the values before using them.